# Constant spinning circle right hand side on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 4 and for the last few days there has been a spinning circle in the right hand side of the status bar. I am wondering why this is.

I've tried turning off the Wi-Fi and restricting cellular data of all apps and nothing has worked. I am worried that there is something wrong with my phone. It seems to be draining my battery also.